# How many anthropomorphic animal races are there?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

I am world building for a Pathfinder campaign. In the world I'm building, I'm thinking about there being a continent extremely linked to nature — most civilizations being primitive, with the landscape surrounding them remaining as natural as possible.

I'm thinking about this continent being inhabited by anthropomorphic animals, to represent how close this continent and those on it are to nature itself.

Is there a complete list of "furry" races in Pathfinder, counting third party content?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to hold off on accepting an answer until at least twenty-four hours have passed, just in case someone posts a better one. It's not a rule, or anything, though.

Comment: Do you consider the were-tigers and such as anthropomorphic animals or do you need them to only have one "hybrid" shape?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Catfolk** - cat

**Ghoran** - tree/plant

**Gnoll** - hyena

**Grippli** - frog

**Kitsune** - fox (can also appear full-blood human)

**Kobold** - lizard

**Ratfolk** - rat

**Syrinx** - owl

**Tengu** - crow

**Trox** - insect

**Vanara** - monkey

---

Here are some honorable mentions:

**Merfolk** - half-fish

**Nagaji/Reptoid/Vishkanya** - lizard-folk

**Orang-Pendak** - sentient apes

**Strix** - humanoids with bird wings

**Wyvaran** - winged lizardfolk (if you have any [flying lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_(genus)) enthusiasts in your group)

---

Those are from Paizo.  I don't know of any third-party.

Comment: There are [flying lizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_(genus)) though.

Comment: Wyvarans are listed as "a fusion of kobolds and wyverns," which to me makes them a poor fit for OP's question.  But I've added them as an honorable mention.